# mount a remote (ssh) usb disk?

Tags: mount, ssh, thunar

My home server has an external USB drive connected. I prefer to keep it unmounted so I don't have to log in if I want to unplug it (for backup rotation).

But I'd also like to be able to browse it in Thunar from my laptop; I tend to do Ctrl+L and `ssh://server/media/me/drive`, it's very nice for copying pictures back and forth (which is not possible with `ssh -X server thunar`)

Is there a simple way to get Thunar, running locally, to make the server mount the drive?

Comment: Maybe autofs can help you; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Comment: seems like a possibility, but does it require a config entry per drive? how does it interact with regular local mounting?